# Can I have both Percentage (100%) and Pixels (-30px) in one CSS selector

Tags: html, css, width

I am modifying a child theme of Wordpress Responsive. 
I am trying to get my H1 post/page headers inside a box, and have been successful.

The trouble is... I need to set the left padding of the Header to 15px, and whenever I do so, the box which the header sits in becomes too wide.

I have the box set to `width: 100%;` I need to use percentages because I'm modifying a responsive theme.
But as I want the inner element (H1) with a `padding-left: 15px;` ... all this does is make the width 100% + 15px, which I don't want.

I am trying to set the box (or the H1 inside) to 100% minus 15px... please can you tell me, **is this even possible?**

... Unfortunately, when I look at the page with Firebug, I see that the `h1 { }` and the other command `.entry-title, .post-title { }` don't seem to be separate in the HTML, like so:

```
<h1 class="entry-title post-title">Header!</h1>
```

I have tried setting one of the two CSS elements to width 100%, and the other to -15px, to no avail. I've also tried some basic dabbling with the z-index, setting one to `z-index: 99;` and the other to `z-index: 1;` , this didn't work either.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function in CSS. For your specific situation, you will want to do something like this:

```
h1 {
    width: calc(100% - 15px);
}
```

That is, providing I understood your question correctly. What the above does is set the width of the `h1` tag to 100% of it's parent element, minus 15px.

Answer (score 0):

I would try `box-sizing: border-box;`.

`h1 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}`

[Check this out for more information.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)